# Gnuplot font embedding

Tags: fonts, gnuplot, embedding

I want to postprocess some figues I made in gnuplot with Corel Draw. However when I create these .eps files no information about the font is included in these. Thus corel does not know what font is build in and get some letters wrong. Especialy the greek ones.

thats the line for the output

```
set terminal postscript enhanced portrait "Times-Roman" 12 size 14cm,12cm                        
set output 'PuckCLnormal.eps
```

and for the special letters

```
set title 'a) {/Symbol q} = 0{/Symbol \260}'
```

How can I thus include the detailed font information in the .eps file so that I can postprocess these gnuplot pics in some other program?

Comment: your code produces postscript that calls for the standard Symbol font. You should not need to 'embed' Symbol. Make sure its not missing from your windows box for some reason.

Comment: Can you please detail your answer a bit more?

Comment: you only need to embed a font if it is something unique. Symbol is literally one of the 6 or 8 core standard fonts that can be assumed universally available.   IMO you are looking at a bug in Corel.  Have you tried opening the file with acrobat?

Comment: Yes and its working ok, but not the correct fonts are displayed

Comment: Ok, in acrobat go to file,properties,fonts and it should say fonts used in this document Times-Roman and Symbol. If it does not show Symbol but Courier or something instead that indicates you dont have symbol installed on your system, go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with this, however, I believe that you need to use something like:

```
fontfile add "path/to/myfont.pfb"
```

Alternatively, I believe that you can use something like:

```
set terminal postscript eps fontfile 'path/to/myfont.ttf'
```

Gnuplot can handle adobe type 1 ASCII (`.pfa`) and binary (`.pfb`) fonts as well as TrueType (`.ttf`).  You can set an environment variable `GNUPLOT_FONTPATH` as well to set the path(s) that gnuplot will search for fontfiles.  Ultimately, check out `help fontfile` for more info.

Comment: Are these fonts somewhat related to latex documents for a latex program like miktex?

Comment: By chance you got also some idea where the standart installation folder for them is? I am working with windows XP or 7. Whats better for you. 

Ps.: I just need one way that works efficiently. I dont want to create some porgramming masterpiece ;)

Comment: Sorry... Not much help for that either.  I don't use Windows (although I'm not sure where they are for *NIX either ... probably need to use `fontconfig` to figure it out).

Comment: Adding the "fontfile" path did not help me either.  But outside GNUplot, running "epstopdf" on the EPS file fixed the problem for me.  I was able to confirm the required fonts being embedded inside the output pdf file using "pdffonts" command-line utility.

Answer (score 0):

If PDF could be used instead of EPS, the `epstopdf` command-line utility helps to embed the fonts into an output PDF file. Using `pdffonts` command-line utility, one can confirm if the fonts are indeed embedded in the PDF file.